# Is this the proper way to create a search function while passing int num? Using a linked list libary

Tags: c++

**Header File:**

```
#ifndef LL_H
#define LL_H

// include this library to use NULL, otherwise use nullptr instead
#include <cstddef>

// include iostream so anything that includes this file can use cout
#include <iostream>

// Struct which will be the building block of our list
struct node
{
    int val;
    node* next;
};

// Contents of 11.h
// Linked list class definition
class LL
{
public:
    LL();
    bool removeFront();
    bool removeBack();
    node* search(int);
    void print();
private:
    node* head;
};
#endif
```

**Source File:**

```
#include "ll.h"

LL::LL()
{
    head = NULL;
}
void LL::search (int num)//heading of the function
{
    node* newNode = new node;
        newNode->val = num;
        newNode->next = NULL;

    while (newNode == NULL)
    {
        if (newNode->val == num)
        {
            return newNode;
        }
        newNode = newNode->next; //point to the next node
    }
    return; //not sure if needed
}
```

The program will read in a
text file called “cmd.txt” that will instruct what operations to run. our program should implement a C++ class which will be used to represent the linked list.

Comment: so you want to use linked list provided by a library or linked list implemented by you?

Comment: `while(curNode == NULL)`: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Are you having issues with your code? `void LL:search` looks wrong, considering it was declared as `node* search`, and having a single colon is straight up wrong.

Comment: You are correct, I just caught that on all my functions.

Comment: current node is the node with value of num being passed to it, so as long as the value of num is equal to the curNode and not NULL then continue.

Comment: This code will never work.  It doesn't even come close to compiling.  Not even a minimal effort.

Comment: @KristoferBeck  I think the question about what was `currNode` also  meant that you should tell the compiler what `currNode` is.  A C++ compiler is not very good at guessing.  Your search returns void, so what's the point of searching?  If you could use a for() loop for searching, should you use that? What is `key`?  Please try to compile the code you post here at a minimum.

Comment: Is there anything different that I would have to do for functions that pass a BOOL? I keep getting an Error prototype of void LL:removeFront() does not match any in class "LL"

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I've rewritten the variable names.

Comment: @Error - Syntactical Remorse corrected the header

Answer (score 1):

Search should look more like:

```
node* LL::Search(int num)
{
    node* current = head;
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current->val == num)
        {
            return current;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct format

```
node* LL::search(int num)
    {
        node* newNode = new node;
        newNode = head;
        while (newNode->next != NULL)
        {
            if (newNode->val == num) 
            {
                return newNode;
            }
        newNode = newNode->next;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```